# How to delete a specific shape from an image without rasterizing the shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, clipping-mask

I have the following image:

[image]

I want to cut the volume slider and acheive the following result:

[image]

Actually I made this a month ago. But now when I tried using the same method it is not working. I made two circles with shape tool then combined them and deleted the intersecting smaller circle. Now I have a ring. With this ring I combined a rectangle and then deleted the semicircle opaqued by the rectangle. Now I have semicircular ring shape which I used as a clipping mask over my music player image. Now when I use magic wand to select that semicircular ring -- so I could delete the selected pixels -- I get the following error:

> Could not use the magic wand because the target is a fill layer.

The workaround is to rasterize the semicircular ring, but then its curves don't remain smooth.

**Edit: ** As suggested in the answer I tried to invert the mask but remained unsuccessful. Pressing `ctrl` + `i` on the masked layer did nothing. Although there is an invert icon in the `adjustment` panel. After pressing this all the white colors in the photoshop window turned white. The layers snapshot after this is as:

[image]

Comment: wait: the volume slider is a vector shape? And you want to delete it? What if you just delete it?

Comment: @Luciano The volume slider is not vector shape. It is a part of the whole image and the whole image is a png image.

Comment: I suppose you should be able to use quick mask or just brush it with the color, you're starting with quite a small image with a lot of noise. You'd get better results by redoing the whole thing using vector objects.

Comment: Brushing it makes pixelated colors. I don't know how to acheive this with quick mask.

Comment: I don't understand if you have the shape, "semicircular ring shape which I used as a clipping mask," then why not use that as a Mask? Or you just don't know how?

Comment: @Ryan I used that as a mask but hides the whole music player leaving only the volume slider visible.

Comment: And you want it to hide the volume slider but leave the rest visible, correct? If so, invert the mask. Take a screenshot of your layer panel to add to the question using the [edit] button.

Comment: Hey, you have a bounty that expires and I still don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ryan I don't know how to invert the mask. Currently when I create the mask volume slider remains visible and remaining music player becomes invisible.

Comment: Please add screenshot showing what the White Player layer looks like without any of the other layers, so I can try to help you out on this. Delete the Background Layer, unclip White_Player (right click it on the layer panel and choose "Release Clipping Mask"), then turn off Ellipse 2 and post a screenshot of what remains on your canvas.

Comment: Is the white_player layer a smart object? Is the content of that smart object layered?

Comment: @Cai No. I just drag and drop white-player.png file onto the background layer. I did not convert it into a smart object.

Comment: @Cai Hmm When I tried to use `clone stamp tool` it says, `this smart object must be rasterized`.

Comment: @user dragging an image in to an existing document will place it as a smart object, but you don't ned it as such in this case so right click the layer and select "Rasterize Layer".

Comment: Then you can use the clone stamp tool or any other raster editing tools on the layer

Comment: Do you want to replace the slider with a transparent "window"? It looks like all the current answers assume you want to replace it with the existing background

Comment: @Cai Yes, I want to to destructively delete the volume slider portion so as to make it transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using the Pen Tool draw a path around the slider. Make sure the Pen tool is set to draw a path, not a shape layer or pixels.

   (or use the shape tools, or copy the paths from your existing shape layers. It doesn't really matter as long as you have a path to work with)

   To use your shape to *hide* the part of the image it covers instead of revealing that part of the image, set your path to *Subtract Front Shape* in the options bar.

[image: Path mode]

[image: Draw a Path]

2. With the correct layer selected in the layers panel, select your path, right click and select *Create Vector Mask*.

[image: Create Vector Mask]

3. Your masked image:

[image: Masked Image]

You could also do the same thing with a selection and a layer mask, which would be more appropriate if you need varying levels of opacity in your mask.

If you want to destructively apply your mask you can right click the mask in the layers panel and select *Rasterize Vector Mask*, which will rasterize the mask, then you right click the mask again and select *Apply Layer Mask*.

Comment: In the 2nd step the `create vector mask` option in my photoshop is fainted and can't be selected. If I select the white-player layer then this option is available but clicking on it deletes the white player itself.

Comment: Is the layer you want to mask selected in the layers panel? That's only reason it would be greyed out as far as I know

Comment: Or if the layer already has a vector mask

Comment: When I select the layer to be masked. It makes the volume slider visible and the rest of the image invisible -- exactly opposite of what I want.

Comment: Oh yeh, my fault I left a bit out... I'll update my answer now!

Comment: Now it is working with the both pen tool and shape tool. May be I by chance had set the shape to path when a month ago I originally did it myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working!

Comment: Can I convert a shape into a path? When I use shape tools like Ellipse tool to draw a ring path, I am not able to use that ring to `create vector mask`.

Comment: Yes, just use the path selection tools (black or white pointers) to select the path and copy. Then select the layer you want to mask and paste.

Comment: You can make the shape tools create paths instead of shapes from the option bar though

Comment: Doing both ways, when I have the ring shaped path, I am unable to use `create vector mask` option. When I right click on the ring path the `create vector mask` is by default disabled.

Comment: If it is disabled, you either don't have the correct layer selected, don't have the path selected or there is already a vector mask on the layer

Comment: If I select the layer to be masked then the path becomes unselected and vice verca. I can't select both the layer to be masked and the path.

Comment: Copy the path, then select the layer to be masked, then paste the path, then with that path selected and the layer to be masked still selected, create your mask

Comment: But all of that is unnecessary if you draw paths (instead of shape layers) with the layer to be masked already selected.

Comment: Having the ring shape path when I create vector mask it creates the mask as a circle not as a ring. How can I create ring shaped mask?